# Protecting a file by a password

Tags: c#, winforms, file, io, password-protection

I have a C# application in which i'd like to create a file :

```
   string fileName = "test.txt";  // a sample file name
        // Delete the file if it exists.
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }
       // Create the file.
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName, 1024))
        {
            // Add some information to the file.
            byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }


        string s = "";
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName))
        {

            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text += s;
            }
        }
```

i need to protect the file by a password outside the program and the file is accessible inside the program without password.

How can i change the snippet to do this task?

Comment: If you have not even tried to do it yourself, please reference the System.Security.Cryptography namespace and give it a go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not protect a text file with a password out of the box.
You would need to encapsulate it, with an other application to do so.

The simplest way, would be to use a Zip File.

As taken form this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607858/how-to-zip-and-unzip-using-password-in-c-sharp-program) by [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso) using [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/):

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password= "VerySecret!!";
    zip.AddFile("test.txt");
    zip.Save("Archive.zip"); 
}
```

This results in 2 steps.

1. Create your files
2. Zip them and choose a password.

Comment: it give me error ZipFile() class

Comment: Good idea - Link is not accessible for me.

Comment: You can get DotNetZip from NuGet now. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/. I've updated the link

Answer (score 2):

You can also encrypt the files if you dont want to create zip files that have compress/uncompress.

[Simple Encryption/Decryption method for encrypting an image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438691/simple-encryption-decryption-method-for-encrypting-an-image-file)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010