# Argument exception in saving a bitmap from a byte array

Tags: c#, bitmap, argumentexception

I have an array of bytes which have legitimate contents but when I try to convert the byte array into a BitMap it throws me an ArgumentException.

```
byte[] oparr = encrypt_function(iparr, keyArr, ivArr);
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(oparr);
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(img);
```

The message which comes is Parameter is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) Wikipedia page:

> The bitmap image file consists of fixed-size structures (headers) as
>   well as variable-size structures appearing in a predetermined
>   sequence.

Judging from the name, your `encrypt_function` will do something to the image at a byte level. This should in turn, affect the internal structure of the bitmap image which I think is why you are getting a `Parameter is Invalid`.

To encrypt the image, you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438691/simple-encryption-decryption-method-for-encrypting-an-image-file) previous SO post.

Comment: Whatever the technique might be, bytes are changed in encryption. So how far the technique that is mentioned takes care of image header? Please clarify me over this.

Comment: @max: It seems to say that you are working at a binary level, so maybe that is why.

Comment: Any encryption algorithm makes the file to operated on a binary level and that disturbs the image file format, right?

Comment: @max: I think so. Did you try to follow the method suggested in the post?

Comment: I was following a method close to the one mentioned in the code said.

Comment: @Max: Then I would recommend you ask a new question and show what methods you are using :).