# Is there a better way of initializing classes?

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm up to making some sort of list of weapons, hardcoding them of course so they can't be hacked or modded without special stuff. And I was just wondering if there's a faster way of doing this:

```
public Firearm(string WeaponName, int WeaponId, float Damage, FireType WeaponFireType, float FireRate, float ReloadTime, int MaxClip, bool InfiniteAmmo)
{
    weaponName = WeaponName;
    weaponID = WeaponId;
    damage = Damage;
    weaponFireType = WeaponFireType;
    fireRate = FireRate;
    reloadTime = ReloadTime;
    maxClip = MaxClip;
    infiniteAmmo = InfiniteAmmo;
}
```

and then later this: (This is just an example, I won't be doing it like this in the actual script.

```
void InitializeWeapons()
{
    var allFirearms = new List<Firearm>();
    allFirearms.Add(new Firearm(
        "Pistol", 
        0, 12.5f, Firearm.FireType.SemiAutomatic, 
        1.2f, 1.5f, 12, true
        )); 
}
```

Is there a different way of doing that? Something that is a little more cleaner and easier to see what is going on?

**Edit:** Kind of sucks I can't put you all as approved answer, since they all helped me learn something and so forth. I'll just go for the one I decide to use. I'll finish the code and approve the one that I used.

Comment: You could use automatic properties and object initialization, but I don't know if that would be "cleaner".

Comment: Seems like you're looking for object initialization syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Maybe you can use [Object Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

Comment: Yes, @MarcinJuraszek & toby. That looks like what I need, looks pretty clear. I'll wait around some more to see some other answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try [Fluent Builder pattern](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/)? The pattern is not without flaws, but it sure makes complex object creation more readable.
First you need to add WeaponBuilder class:

```
public class WeaponBuilder
{
    private string name;
    private int damage;
    private int fireRate;

    public WeaponBuilder CreateWeapon(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public WeaponBuilder WithDamage(int damage)
    {
        this.damage = damage;
        return this;
    }

    public WeaponBuilder WithFireRate(int fireRate)
    {
        this.fireRate = fireRate;
        return this;
    }

    public Weapon Build()
    {
        return new Weapon(name, damage, fireRate);
    }
}
```

And then you create your Weapons like this:

```
    var weapon = new WeaponBuilder()
        .CreateWeapon("AK-47")
        .WithDamage(100)
        .WithFireRate(50)
        .Build();
```

Comment: So many ways to do the same thing, I'll have to try some of them out and decide for the best thing. This one seems kind of cool, too. How to apply that in the a list?

Comment: Do I apply that in a list, like so?

`list.Add(new Weapon()  
    .CreateWeapon("Pistol")  
    .WithDamage(2000)  
    .WithFireRate(2000000)  
     //ETC  
    .Build());`  

or in a different way?

Comment: That should work, but you can also combine it with object initializer: http://pastie.org/10302772

Comment: That is wonderful, I'll use that one. Thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as I finished the code for it.

Comment: actually.. I've got another question. If I forget one statement, for example withFireRate. Will it stop working?

Comment: That's one of the downsides of this pattern.When using regular constructor, the compiler will complain if any parameter's missing. Here, when you forget to set `fireRate` it will be set to default `float` value which is `0.0F`. You have to write the logic, preventing that kind of situations yourself (e.g. check in `Weapon` constructor, that value passed is not default and raise an `Exception` if it is).

Comment: I would think making the WeaponBuilder class static with only static methods would eliminate the need for instantiating the WeaponBuilder class itself.

Comment: It's quite easy to fix acutally, just have CreateWeapon define standard values, and the rest is optional to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write down the information into some configuration file.
2. Add code that reads configuration file in iteration and creates objects you need.

   - Cons: 
     You need to spend a time to create a configuration file.
   - Pros: 
     Once you have it, the code becomes *clearer* and *scallable*, open for future possible expansions and solutions.

Comment: Thanks. But I want something else, that can be hardcoded.

Comment: I was thinking this as well but doesn't that conflict with his "hardcoding them of course so they can't be hacked or modded without special stuff" ? A configuration file i pretty easy to change, if no measures are taken to make them unreadable.

Comment: @Dyrborg: you make it binary, so it's faster to read and process, and hard to decode.

Comment: I can do this, too. I have no idea how to make it binary though, and I'll need to look in XML serialization a little.. but I'll figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But then you would still have to create the objects themselves and save them to a file. Doesn't really make his current code cleaner.

Comment: @Dyrborg I'm not really talking about making the code cleaner, but the initialization of things. Just so that I can go in, edit stuff with exactly knowing what I'm editing. Save it and run and see the edits. Something like that. I don't mind having a separate class for XML/??? serialization, de-serialization and encrypting stuff.

Would XML actually work, or is there some alternative I can do? How hard is creating my own style?

Comment: @Dyrborg: if the information is "static", in sense it's known before runtime, you can pretty much come up with clever file structure, to holde all necessary to you object types and permutations.

Comment: @Stepepper: if you are thinking about binary, it's not about XML serialization. The thing is: is this information, the information you push into objects, is known at startup, or it is dynamically created information? Based on some events/conditions..

Comment: You could alternately store the information in an embedded resource.

Comment: As I'm using Unity for this, it is actually known when a GameObject gets created. The game starts, and all the objects get created, before the game actually gets loaded, the objects' Start() function gets called. That's where this is in. So I'd say it's known at startup.

Comment: So if the configuration of different objects (initial only or permanent) is known, you can store it inside some file, or sqlite database, embede resource (as suggested) or any other binary storage with fast read access.

Comment: Alternatively you can write an XML file with a well known structure and encrypt it as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438691/simple-encryption-decryption-method-for-encrypting-an-image-file

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [T4 Text Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx):

- Store your weapons in a database/config file, etc. in your development environment.
- Generates code at compile time, so your data is hardcoded.

Your code might be ugly, but the data file will be much more maintainable, and you can even use a database or shared file to store the data.

To use it, create a file with .tt extension in Visual Studio. Looks something like this:

*The following code is not tested*

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

namespace Foo {
    class Bar {

        static void InitBar() {

<# 
            // Create an object for every line:
            // Create an object for every line:
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("testfile");
            foreach(var line in lines) {
              <#= var newObject = new Weapon("#> line <#= "); #>
            }
#>
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what's going on in the documentation. What's with the <#@ ... #> everywhere?

Comment: Code between <# and #> are executed in Visual Studio, to generate the .cs file.